# How to get a CCITT-CRC16 on Python's crcmod lybrary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, crc16

I'm having problems to make a code in Python 3.4 using the CRCMOD library to get the CCITT CRC16 check.

Thats my string:

```
a731986b1500087f9206e82e3829fe8bcffed5555efd00a100980000010000000100000009010013bb1d001e287107009b3000000300000088330000f427500077026309
```

The spected crc value is **1d7f**

My code:

```
import crcmod

crc16 = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x11021, 0x1d0f, False, 0x0000)

hex(crc16(b'a731986b1500087f9206e82e3829fe8bcffed5555efd00a100980000010000000100000009010013bb1d001e287107009b3000000300000088330000f427500077026309'))
```

It returns: **7d67**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the initial string isn't just a hex representation of binary data ? (i.e. you'll have to convert the hex to binary before calculating the crc)

Comment: Yes, man. I saw it now... have you a tip for me with how can I convert it into HEX??? I try hex('ba7.....) but it doesn't work.

Comment: `import binascii` `binascii.a2b_hex('a731 ....')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You first need to convert the data from its hex representation to binary. You also need to use the correct CRC algorithm, which I think is "xmodem" - `crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x11021, 0x0000, False, 0x0000)`

```
import crcmod.predefined
from binascii import unhexlify

s = unhexlify('a731986b1500087f9206e82e3829fe8bcffed5555efd00a100980000010000000100000009010013bb1d001e287107009b3000000300000088330000f427500077026309')

crc16 = crcmod.predefined.Crc('xmodem')
crc16.update(s)
print crc16.hexdigest()
```

Outputs **7F1D** (which is what you expected but with the bytes reversed)

Comment: @Uri: you are correct for Python 2, however, the OP has tagged the question as Python 3 which does not support direct hex decoding of strings.

Comment: why the ouput is reversed? how I get the real ouput 1d7f?